# Extract strings with SOME unique characters in R

Tags: r, string, string-comparison

Here is my pb:
I have 9 strings, all unique but with characters in common. I want to extract among them the ones that have some unique characters, not present in any other string.
I think that a loop which compare each string with the others is a good option but I don't know which function to use.I can't use the unique() function as all the string are unique.

Here are the strings:

[1] ".contexte d'enseignement""
[2] ".contexte d'enseignement.cohérence avec le niveau des élèves""
[3] ".contexte d'enseignement.contraintes pratiques""
[4] ".contexte d'enseignement.contraintes pratiques.contrainte de temps""
[5] ".contexte d'enseignement.contraintes pratiques.contrainte matérielle""
[6] ".contexte d'enseignement.contraintes pratiques.faisabilité par rapport à la classe""
[7] ".contexte d'enseignement.objectifs de l'Education Nationale""
[8] ".contexte d'enseignement.objectifs de l'Education Nationale.adéquation avec le programme""
[9] ".contexte d'enseignement.objectifs de l'Education Nationale.progression de la difficulté""

And this is the result I'm waiting for:

[1] ".contexte d'enseignement.cohérence avec le niveau des élèves""
[2] ".contexte d'enseignement.contraintes pratiques.contrainte de temps""
[3] ".contexte d'enseignement.contraintes pratiques.contrainte matérielle""
[4] ".contexte d'enseignement.contraintes pratiques.faisabilité par rapport à la classe""
[5] ".contexte d'enseignement.objectifs de l'Education Nationale.adéquation avec le programme""
[6] ".contexte d'enseignement.objectifs de l'Education Nationale.progression de la difficulté""

Thank's for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this with `sapply()`.  In the code below, `sapply()` is used to loop over all of the observation numbers in the string.  It used `str_detect()` from the `stringr` package to identify whether the ith value of `str` in its entirety is in any of the other values of `str`.  Wrapping the output from `str_detect()`  in `any()` will evaluate to `TRUE` if the ith string is in any of the other strings.  Then you can use that result to subset the string to create the desired output.

```
str <- c(".contexte d\'enseignement",
".contexte d\'enseignement.cohérence avec le niveau des élèves",
".contexte d\'enseignement.contraintes pratiques",
".contexte d\'enseignement.contraintes pratiques.contrainte de temps",
".contexte d\'enseignement.contraintes pratiques.contrainte matérielle",
".contexte d\'enseignement.contraintes pratiques.faisabilité par rapport à la classe",
".contexte d\'enseignement.objectifs de l\'Education Nationale",
".contexte d\'enseignement.objectifs de l\'Education Nationale.adéquation avec le programme",
".contexte d\'enseignement.objectifs de l\'Education Nationale.progression de la difficulté")

library(stringr)
w <- sapply(1:length(str), 
            function(x)any(str_detect(str[-x], str[x])))
str[-which(w)]
# [1] ".contexte d'enseignement.cohérence avec le niveau des élèves"                            
# [2] ".contexte d'enseignement.contraintes pratiques.contrainte de temps"                      
# [3] ".contexte d'enseignement.contraintes pratiques.contrainte matérielle"                    
# [4] ".contexte d'enseignement.contraintes pratiques.faisabilité par rapport à la classe"      
# [5] ".contexte d'enseignement.objectifs de l'Education Nationale.adéquation avec le programme"
# [6] ".contexte d'enseignement.objectifs de l'Education Nationale.progression de la difficulté"
```

Comment: I've tried it and it actually works well! Thank you ;)